# Using Rest Codeigniter library with Twitter API

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, twitter, rest-client

I have setup the Rest library by Phil Sturgeon to connect to the Twitter API - it works great however (see below)

```
    $this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');
    $this->load->library('rest');
    $this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://twitter.com/'));
    $username = 'my-username';
    // Pull in an array of tweets
    $tweets = $this->rest->get('statuses/user_timeline/'.$username.'.xml');
```

This code works great - however the Twitter API [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) recommend using a slightly different approach (see below) - how would I use the newer approach below with this library?

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward as follows:

```
$this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');
$this->load->library('rest');
$this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://api.twitter.com'));
$username = 'my-username';
// Pull in an array of tweets
$tweets = $this->rest->get('/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name='.$username);
```

Unless I'm missing something.

You can add any of the other querystring parameters listed on the docs page.

Comment: Not sure if this was part of @Zabs' question, but the same approach can of course request JSON by changing the extension in its request for `user_timeline`.

Comment: That returns a 'Not authorized' error, it is strange as it does look very straightforward - although I can see the first attempt I provided returns an XML document, while the later returns json values.